# Bundle.js RefferenceError browser is not defined

Tags: javascript

picture says it all, in Chrome dev tools. Bundle.js is throwing error when debugging a react-native app. browser is not defined. any ideas. new to npm and react-native.

[image]

Comment: I see you are using Grammarly (you are in its context in the console), it sometimes causes weird bugs, try disabling it out.

Comment: Hi so it looks like Grammarly was the issue here, I do not have any errors however now the project does not show up. Just the Default React page. @yuriy636